# How do I set the color of a single pixel in a Direct3D texture?

Tags: c++, graphics, directx, direct3d

I'm attempting to draw a 2D image to the screen in Direct3D, which I'm assuming must be done by mapping a texture to a rectangular billboard polygon projected to fill the screen.  (I'm not interested or cannot use Direct2D.)  All the texture information I've found in the SDK describes loading a bitmap from a file and assigning a texture to use that bitmap, but I haven't yet found a way to manipulate a texture as a bitmap pixel by pixel.

What I'd really like is a function such as

`void TextureBitmap::SetBitmapPixel(int x, int y, DWORD color);`

If I can't set the pixels directly in the texture object, do I need to keep around a DWORD array that is the bitmap and then assign the texture to that every frame?

Finally, while I'm initially assuming that I'll be doing this on the CPU, the per-pixel color calculations could probably also be done on the GPU.  Is the HLSL code that sets the color of a single pixel in a texture, or are pixel shaders only useful for modifying the display pixels?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, your direct question:

You can, technically, set pixels in a texture. That would require use of [LockRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205913(VS.85).aspx) and [UnlockRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205914(VS.85).aspx) API.

In D3D context, 'locking' usually refers to transferring a resource from GPU memory to system memory (thereby disabling its participation in rendering operations). Once locked, you can modify the populated buffer as you wish, and then unlock - i.e., transfer the modified data back to the GPU. 
Generally locking was considered a very expensive operation, but since [PCIe 2.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#PCI_Express_2.0) that is probably not a major concern anymore. You can also specify a small (even 1-pixel) RECT as a 2nd argument to LockRect, thereby requiring the memory-transfer of a negligible data volume, and hope the driver is indeed smart enough to transfer just that (I know for a fact that in older nVidia drivers this was not the case).

The more efficient (and code-intensive) way of achieving that, is indeed to never leave the GPU. If you [create your texture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174363(VS.85).aspx) as a RenderTarget (that is, specify D3DUSAGE_RENDERTARGET as its [usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172625(VS.85).aspx) argument), you could then set it as the destination of the pipeline before making any draw calls, and write a shader (perhaps [passing parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205728(VS.85).aspx)) to paint your pixels.  Such usage of render targets is considered standard, and you should be able to find many code samples around - but unless you're already facing performance issues, I'd say that's an overkill for a single 2D billboard.

HTH.